# How to test a BaseModel class with fields retrieved from a method?

Tags: python, pytest, pydantic

I find myself writing tests for methods for two classes, one of which has str fields that it retrieves from another BaseModel class:

```py
class Person(BaseModel):
    firstname: Optional[str] = settings.get_settings().firstname
    lastname: Optional[str] = settings.get_settings().lastname
```

Now, when I try to create the fixture I get this problem

```py
#test file

@pytest.fixture
def person_class():
    person = Person(
        firstname="Marco",
        lastname="Marche"
    )
    return person()
```

Error:
`pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 31 validation errors for Settings`

Settings is a BaseSettings class.

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    firstname: str,
    lastname: str,
    address: str,
    telephone: str

@lru_cache
def get_settings() -> Settings:
    return Settings()
```

How can I solve it by creating a "fake" Person class with fields entered by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a typo in your `Settings` definition and there should be no commas in the `firstname`, `lastname`, and `address` lines.

The error you're getting is most likely because your `Settings` class requires a value for `firstname`, `lastname`, and the other fields but you didn't provide any.

I think the easiest solution would be to give it some fake values in the instantiation in your `get_settings()` function, e.g.:

```py
@lru_cache
def get_settings() -> Settings:
    return Settings(
        firstname="fake firstname",
        lastname="fake lastname",
        address="fake address",
        telephone="fake telephone",
    )
```

Pydantic does provide the `construct()` method on the Models which allows to [create models without validation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#creating-models-without-validation), however, I don't think this would work in your situation because you are getting the default values for `Person` from `Settings` which, in a case like yours, is still being evaluated.